# Sql sum values different id

Tags: sql, mysql-python

i have a simple table . How can i sum  in SQL only values based on Riclass ID?

| Riclass_Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 92751 |
| 3 | 56757 |
| 4 | 64666 |
| 5 | 88888 |

I tried  this code but doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
Riclass_ID
SUM (Value)
FROM Mytable
WHERE Riclass_Id= 0 and Riclass_Id= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop `Riclass_ID` from `Select`

```
SELECT SUM (Value)
  FROM Mytable
 WHERE Riclass_Id in (0, 3)
```

and you'll get a single record - sum of all `Value`s which belong to records with `Riclass_Id` equals to either `0` or `3`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum by `Riclass_ID` you need use `group by` clause : choose fields to be grouped

If you want only some `Riclass_ID`, you need use `where` clause : choose the value to be filtered

With `group by` clause, you can select only :

- aggregat function (here `SUM(value)`, or `count(*)`, or `min/max`...)
- fields specify in `group by`
- const

With one (or more) aggregat function in the `select`clause AND without `group by` clause, you can't select fields without aggregat.

```
SELECT 
    Riclass_ID,
    SUM (Value)
FROM
    Mytable
WHERE
    Riclass_Id in (0,3)
GROUP BY 
    Riclass_Id
```